# jQuery UI sortable with table and modal pop ups

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

**One**: I need a table with sortable rows (see jqueryui.com). Typically, the examples give you list items but it is very possible to do this with table rows. Here's my homework http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/ and his jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/tzYbU/ He basically explains the fixes that go along with making table rows sortable.

**Two**: I need these sortable table rows to have a modal pop up on hover. It seems I can only have one or the other. Either the sortable rows move, but the pop up doesn't work (http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/gAmnQ/2/ it's sorting/dragging on my end but not the fiddle) **or** the modal pop ups work and and sort, but it's list items. (http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/gAmnQ/1/). Then there's the strange occurrence where a row is kicked out of the table and only it's hover works (http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/gAmnQ/2/). Anyways, I need rows due to correct spacing and the fact that I will also need to dynamically create new rows. Any ideas?

**Here's the HTML for my sortable table:**

```
<table class="table_177" id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable inputboxes">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Vessel Name</th>
    <th>Hull/IMO No.</th>
  </tr>
</thead>  
  <tr>
    <a class="productsModal1" style="text-decoration:none">
    <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-right:none">SS Mary Mae</td>
    <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-left:none">12345</td></a>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <a class="productsModal1" style="text-decoration:none">
    <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-right:none">EMS 234</td>
    <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-left:none">12346</td></a>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

The HTML and CSS for my hidden modals:

```
<style>
div.productsModal1
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:8px;
    background-color:white;
}
a.productsModal1:hover + div.productsModal1
{
    display:block;
/*  animation:fade-out .5s 1;
    animation-transition-property: opacity;*/
}
div.productsModal1:hover
{
    display:block;
/*  animation:fade-out .5s 1;
    animation-transition-property: opacity;*/
}
</style>
    <div class="productsModal1" style="top: 230px; left: 320px; z-index:9999" >
  <table id="menu1">
    <tr>
      <th>Vessel Name</th>
      <th>Vessel Type</th>
      <th>Hull/IMO No.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SS Mary Mae</td>
      <td>Barge</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div class="productsModal1" style="top: 230px; left: 320px; z-index:9999" >
  <table id="menu1">
    <tr>
      <th>Vessel Name</th>
      <th>Vessel Type</th>
      <th>Hull/IMO No.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EMS 234</td>
      <td>Barge</td>
      <td>67891</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

**AND my code:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Return a helper with preserved width of cells
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index)
    {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
};
    $("#sortable2 tbody").sortable({helper: fixHelperModified}).disableSelection();
});//]]>
```

Comment: I don't think anchor tags are valid childrens of `<tr>` tags.. or valid parents of `<td>` [TR Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/tr) , [TD Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/td).. Also are you looking for one table with sortable rows?  Or multiple tables?

Comment: Just one table. The table needs to be sortable and have pop up modals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, remove the anchor tags wrapping the `td` because that is invalid HTML.. and add the class to your tr, also use the data-index to store the default index since you will be moving them around and need a way to relate them to the modal

Change the tr to this

```
<tr class="productsModal1" data-index=0>
  <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-right:none">SS Mary Mae</td>
  <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-left:none">12345</td>
</tr>
<tr class="productsModal1" data-index=1>
  <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-right:none">EMS 234</td>
  <td class="ui-state-highlight" style="border-left:none">12346</td>
</tr>
```

- Not sure why $(window).load function wasn't working.. but using document.ready function fixed the fiddle of sorting not working..
- You can then use jQuery to show/hide the relevant divs

JS

```
$('#sortable2 tbody tr').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')) // <-- this gets the div.. though the share the same class so can probably just hardcode
            .eq($(this).data('index')) // <-- gets the correct one according to data-index
            .show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $('div.' + $(this).attr('class'))
            .eq($(this).data('index'))
            .hide();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/99Mdz/)

One other thing is if you don't want to go in and hardcode the data attributes.  You can just write use jQuery inside the document.ready function and dynamically add it.

```
$('#sortable2 tbody tr').each(function(i,v){
     $(this).data('index',i);
});
```

Comment: Perfect fix, once again @Wirey.

Comment: Okay. So I could previously add new rows to the sortable table, with the new code I can't. Any idead how to implement that? There is user input boxes, they type their information and click the button. The information adds to the sortable table with the same hover modal functionality. When I had it previously working, visually it looked correct, but it didn't have the modals and it stopped the rest of the table from sorting. Maybe because I'm using innerHTML rather than jQuery? Either will work.

Comment: So you are dynamically creating the divs modal divs too?

Comment: @triplethreat77 let me know if this helps you figure it out http://jsfiddle.net/5f5xy/

Comment: That's it. The only hang up is something i didn't mention. Each other row has a "zebra" effect    $("tr:even td").addClass("zebraEven");
   $("tr:odd td").addClass("zebraOdd"); to make every other row a different color. clone only takes the last color.

Comment: Haha got it! Added the above code under .appendTo('sortable2 tbody'); duh.

Comment: One more thing. I need the selected option from a drop down. Is this similar to the input[name=num] scenario?

Comment: What do you mean the selected option from a dropdown?  So inputs should be dropdowns?

Comment: I need inputs and drop downs. In the example you have in jsfiddle, "barge" is part of a drop down. Another user chosen value. Also, I noticed in my local version of the page (because it seems to work in fiddle) once I add a new row, my previous rows no longer have the hover modal.

Comment: @triplethreat77 hmmm.. do your new rows have the hover modal?  Did you delegate the hover event as shown in the fiddle?  I changed it up since you were dynamically adding elements..  Also for select you can do the same thing and just modify the text as the others http://jsfiddle.net/AGEt5/

Comment: I know why. I removed data-index from my rows because I misunderstood your comment containing $('#sortable2 tbody tr').each(function(i,v){
     $(this).data('index',i);
});

Comment: here's another one to up your reputation. @wirey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529886/sort-a-table-by-drop-down-values-simplify-my-code