# Sort a table by drop down values (simplify my code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, filter

I have a table. I want the user to be able to be able to filter the table by the option they pick in a given drop down. I have it working, but it's messy and hard to add new rows with (can't get it working in jsfiddle, sorry http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/Y4cf6/2/). Any simplified code would be greatly appreciated. Also, it would be nice if this code could be restricted to only filtering a certain table, so I can have many tables and many drop downs. If this could be done without row ids, even better. Thanks! **My table/html:**

```
<table>
<tr id="catRow">
  <td id="cats">cats</td>
</tr>
<tr id="catRow2">
  <td id="cats">cats</td>
</tr>
<tr id="dogRow">
  <td id="dogs">dogs</td>
</tr>
<tr id="birdRow">
  <td id="birds">birds</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="dogRow2">dogs</td>
</tr>
</table>

                <select id="selectFilter">
                <option id="sel_All">Select...</option>
                <option id="selCats">Cats</option>
                <option id="selDogs">Dogs</option>
                <option id="selBirds">Birds</option>
                </select>
```

**Code:**

```
   <script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(window).load(function(){
     $('select').change(function() {

  if($('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "sel_All" || $('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "sel_All"){$('#catRow').show();$('#catRow2').show();$('#dogRow').show();$('#dogRow2').show();$('#birdRow').show();}

  if($('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "selCats" || $('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "selCats"){$('#catRow').show();$('#catRow2').show();$('#dogRow').hide();$('#dogRow2').hide();$('#birdRow').hide();}

  if($('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "selDogs" || $('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "selDogs"){$('#catRow').hide();$('#catRow2').hide();$('#dogRow').show();$('#dogRow2').show();$('#birdRow').hide();}

  if($('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "selBirds" || $('#selectFilter option:selected').attr('id') == "selBirds"){$('#catRow').hide();$('#catRow2').hide();$('#dogRow').hide();$('#dogRow2').hide();$('#birdRow').show();}
    </script>
```

Comment: wait.. you want to sort or filter?  I might have misunderstood

Comment: You may want to link to a working jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the refactored code "http://jsfiddle.net/5fZv7/3/" here and the code snippet is as below..

html code:

```
<select id="selectFilter">
       <option id="all">Select...</option>
       <option id="cats">Cats</option>
       <option id="dogs">Dogs</option>
       <option id="birds">Birds</option>
</select>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="all cats">
    <td>cats</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="all cats">
    <td>cats 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="all dogs">
    <td>dogs</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="all birds">
    <td>birds</td>
 </tr>
```

and the javascript code:

```
 $(document).load(function () {
   $('#selectFilter').change(function () {
     $(".all").hide();
     $("." + $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")).show();
   });
 });
```

Hopes this helps you to maintain the code easily and efficiently.

Comment: Working! Beautiful, everything I asked for. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I've refactored your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4cf6/4/

By taking advantage of CSS classes and built-in attributes like "value", we can easily make this code more generic.

For this HTML:

```
<table id="animals">
    <tr class="cat">
        <td>Cat 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat">
        <td>Cat 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dog">
        <td>Dog 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat">
        <td>Cat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bird">
        <td>Bird 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat">
        <td>Cat 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dog">
        <td>Dog 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<select id="selectFilter">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option value="cat">Cats</option>
    <option value="dog">Dogs</option>
    <option value="bird">Birds</option>
</select>
```

The Javascript is reduced to essentially a one-liner:

```
$("#selectFilter").on("change", function() {
    $("#animals").find("tr").hide().filter("." + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Edit: the one case this doesn't handle is giving you a way to show all the rows again. I'll leave this as an exercise for you, but here's a tip: You could read the value of `$(this).val()`, and if there isn't a value, then show all the rows instead of filtering them.

Comment: Just remember that IDs should be unique in the whole document, whereas classes are great to reuse everywhere you have the same type-- or "class"-- of content!

Comment: Eh, tried to implement it on the page and it clears my entire table. :/ Not a solution for this case.

Comment: Likely a problem with the markup on your page-- check the fiddle for a working example.

Comment: This is good.. the only odd thing is if no filter is selected.. why are all the tr's hidden?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your html markup like this

```
<table id='animal'>
  <tr class="cat">
    <td>cats</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cat">
    <td>cats</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dog">
    <td>dogs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bird">
    <td>birds</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='dog'>
    <td>dogs</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<select id="selectFilter">
  <option value=''>Select...</option>
  <option value='cat'>Cats</option>
  <option value='dog'>Dogs</option>
  <option value='bird'>Birds</option>
</select>
```

Then your jQuery

```
$('#selectFilter').change(function(){
    var trs = $('#animal tr'); 
    if(this.value == ''){  // if first option picked show all
         trs.show(); 
    }else{
       var $el = $('.'+this.value);  // element to show
       trs.not($el).hide(); // hide all but the elements to show
       $el.show();       // show elements
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EmHMH/)

Comment: It isn't making any changes.  Not sure what to tell you.

Comment: @triplethreat77 did you change the tr `id's` to classes?  make sure your option has the correct values also..  and always wrap these binding codes inside of a document.ready function

Comment: Another filtering case, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530741/filter-a-table-by-input-value-on-key-up-simplify-my-code

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), it has this kind of filtering built in (fnFilter in the [API](http://datatables.net/api))

It might be a bit of a learning curve at first, but will be much more flexible in the end.

Comment: I can't use datatables. It's amazing, but way too heavy. I would have to rebuild the entire site around it. Believe me, I tried.

Comment: Too bad. Do you mean too heavy because it is complicated to use? Can you elaborate more on what you are building?

Comment: I got the solution below. I'm fixing a very broken site and it's kind of a patch up job. Any new script throws everything off, so I need simple solutions.